# Configure a connection retry for a Redis instance

Tags: symfony, redis

I plan to move my web site to a cloud one. I've been told there is some micro-interruptions in some services.

Therefore I'd like to configure a connection retry for the redis cache set up.

I'm using Symfony 4.2 with this configuration

```
framework:
  cache:
    app: cache.adapter.redis
    default_redis_provider: '%env(REDIS_URL)%'
```

Is there any way to configure the `retry_interval` option of redis in Symfony ?

EDIT : including precisions of @simon.ro

Answer (score 0):

Redis has an option `retry_interval` which you can specify at connect-time. You should check the documentation of the redis connecting library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The `default_redis_provider` is a DSN that will be parsed with [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function

So you can add parameters into query string like this :

```
default_redis_provider: 'redis://u:pass@localhost/2:6379?retry_interval=300&timeout=10&read_timeout=30&tcp_keepalive=10'
```

path of url `/2` is the dbindex of redis